# For Jmeter Bearer authorization token request, Getting org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException

Tags: jmeter, bearer-token

I am sending a HTTPS request which needs a Bearer token. I have added a Header Manager to my HTTP request in JMeter and defined NAMEand VALUE in the Header Manager as Authorization and "Bearer xxxxyxyxyxz" respectively.

The request is running for 21 seconds each time and then its failed with below text

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to abcd.uat.xyz.com:443 [abcd.uat.xyz.com/11.222.250.10] failed: Connection timed out: connect.
```

Am I sending the bearer token in right way with Header Manager or is there some other way to send this kind of requests?

Note: Its(The same request and Bearer token) working perfectly in Postman and I am getting the correct response as well.

Comment: Show your Header manager

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved after adding Proxy Server details to the request. I have added those in Advanced section of HTTP request.

In Postman, the tool using default system proxy settings, hence working without any issues but when it comes to Jmeter we need to add Proxy Server details explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception it seems, you are trying to access HTTP server with HTTPS request.

Make sure to confirm whether "abcd.uat.xyz.com:443" support https or not..If not simply make your request HTTP by updating Protocol field.